# How to add regular expression in textbox key down event?VB.NET windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have this R.E validator `^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$`,How to add this validator in `textbox` ,I am creating vb.net windows forms appliation.
I want insert automatically dashes when user enter his/her cnic num like in pakistani format : `3240X-XXXXXXX-X`

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to wait until the user completed data entry.  Use the Validating event.  This isn't anything that MaskedTextBox can't do btw, its advantage is that it works while the user is busy typing.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Hans said - the easiest way is with a MaskedTextBox: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

You will just create your mask to match your criteria, so probably 00000-0000000-0
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

For something else - you'd need to create your own method on the KeyUp Event - something like here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?758387-VBA-Adding-Dashes-Automatically-Into-Text-Box